# What does "it" in "day of it" refer to?

Tags: meaning

Armand approaches boatman, who is at campfire:

> Armand: Room for one more at your fire?
>
> Boatman: You look like you've had a day of **it**.

What does "it" in "day of it" refer to?

Comment: Compare [***Let's make a day of it***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22let%27s+make+a+day+of+it%22), where "it" has the same general sense of "the current situation". To make a day of it means to devote the entire day to doing something (usually, something that will make that day particularly ***memorable***). I suppose you could say "it" in both my and OP's example refer to (the current) "day", as in ***It's raining today*** - but if you ask native speakers what "it" refers to in ***It's sunny***, I imagine most of them would say ***Nothing in particular***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression means that Boatman thinks Armand's appearance shows that he's had a full day of doing something difficult or tiring.
You could say that *it* refers to the difficulties or efforts of the day.